# Can I edit my posts on the telegra.ph web using my account created by API

Tags: telegraph

I created an account through [Telegraph API](https://telegra.ph/api#createAccount) and created pages by API. However, I don't know how to create or edit pages through [Telegraph Web](https://telegra.ph/) with this account created by API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [Telegraph API#getAccountInfo](https://telegra.ph/api#getAccountInfo) has a field called `auth_url`. I could use this URL to log in the telegraph web.